# Array of elements is not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I have the following mongoose schema

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    field1: [{
        format: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    field2: [{
        format: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
});
```

To get the input for this model I am creating a form which has the array of controls and the code is below

Even If if try to use the `$scope.field1[<index>]` it give the error that

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12 padding-left-0">
    <label for="question">Field1 Values</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="(optionKey, optionValue) in [0,1]">
    <ng-form name="field1Form{{optionKey}}">
      <div class="col-md-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_format.$invalid }">
        <label for="field1_format">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="field1_format" id="field1_format" data-ng-model="form.field1[$index].format" required>
          <option value="text" selected="selected">Text</option>
          <option value="image">Image</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-show="submitted && field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_format.$invalid" class="help-block">
          <p ng-show="field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_format.$error.required">Field1 type is required</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_value.$invalid }">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label for="field1_value">Value</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1_value" id="field1_value" data-ng-model="form.field1[$index].value" placeholder="Enter field1 value" required/>
          <div ng-show="submitted && field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_value.$invalid" class="help-block">
            <p ng-show="field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_value.$error.required">Field1 value is required</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12 padding-left-0" data-ng-show="true">
  <div class="col-md-12 padding-left-0"><label>Field2 Values</label></div>
  <div class="col-md-6" data-ng-repeat="i in [0,1]">
    <ng-form name="field2Form{{i}}">
      <label>Value-{{i+1}}</label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && field2Form{{i}}.field2_format.$invalid }">
          <label for="field2_format">Type</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="field2_format" id="field2_format" data-ng-model="form.field2[$index].format" required>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="image">Image</option>
          </select>
          <div ng-show="submitted && field2Form{{i}}.field2_format.$invalid" class="help-block">
            <p ng-show="field2Form{{i}}.field2_format.$error.required">Field2 type is required</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && field2Form{{i}}.field2_value.$invalid }">
          <label for="field2_value">Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field2_value" id="field2_value" data-ng-model="form.field2[$index].value" placeholder="Enter Value {{i+1}}" required/>
          <div ng-show="submitted && field2Form{{i}}.field2_value.$invalid" class="help-block">
            <p ng-show="field2Form{{i}}.field2_value.$error.required">Field2 value is required</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

But in the angular controller I am getting the array of object values for field2 but field1 is not coming (missing) from the form data.

But when I hard code the question array like below for field1 then field1 also work fine

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ng-form name="field1Form0">
      <div class="col-md-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && field1Form0.field1_format.$invalid }">
        <label for="field1_format">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="field1_format" id="field1_format" data-ng-model="form.field1[0].format" required>
          <option value="text">Text</option>
          <option value="image">Image</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-show="submitted && field1Form0.field1_format.$invalid" class="help-block">
          <p ng-show="field1Form0.field1_format.$error.required">Field1 type is required</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && field1Form0.field1_value.$invalid }">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label for="field1_value">Value</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1_value" id="field1_value" data-ng-model="form.field1[0].value" placeholder="Enter field1" required/>
          <div ng-show="submitted && field1Form0.field1_value.$invalid" class="help-block">
            <p ng-show="field1Form0.field1_value.$error.required">Question value is required</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </ng-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: can you add the angular code from the controller too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like some angular issue.

It has been fixed by declaring the variable in `angular Controller` like below

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.form.field1 = {};
```

Now its working fine. **May be the issue in auto declaring the `nested objects or array` in angular.**

Answer (score 0):

It very possible you've got a lot of things mixed up.

- One of them you have already recognised - the scope didn't have a `form` property.
- The expression `field1Form{{optionKey}}.field1_format.$invalid` is not valid, because string interpolation cannot be used in the context where it's found. As far as I know, ***ng-class*** and ***ng-show*** directives expect a JavaScript expression, not a template. My point is this clearly, the interpolation expression `{{optionKey}}`, should not be used in ***ng-class*** and ***ng-show*** directives.

Comment: But all of this its working now, because this {{optionKey}} render in html to the [0,1] so it becoms field1Form0_field1_format.$invalid